# Use Multiprocessing to update values in a list of class instances

Tags: python, oop, multiprocessing

I have seen some suggestions that I should not even do this using multiprocessing, or that's not the way to use multiprocessing (memory sharing), but I'm going to ask anyway and see if I can understand it better.

I have a Person class, and I want to update the age of that person using `update_age` method. Let's say I have millions of the Person object (instead of 4 shown here), and I want to use Multiprocessing to update the age of all the Person instances I have.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def update_age(self):
        self.age += 10

people = [Person(1), Person(2), Person(3), Person(4)]

p = Pool(4)

results = [p.apply_async(person.update_age, ()) for person in people]

print([res.get() for res in results])
```

This will give me `[None, None, None, None]` because the method Person.update_age does not return anything. If I change the class to:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def update_age(self):
        return self.age + 10
```

I would get the correct response `[11, 12, 13, 14]`. But that requires me to restructure all the methods in that class. That is a lot of work if I developed the `Person` class without thinking about scalability.
Is there any way for me to keep the original structure of the class, and still be able to use multiprocessing to spread out the workload to all my CPUs?

**EDIT**: So if I have a method in the parent process like this.

```
def update_all():
  for person in people:
    person.update_age()
```

What would be the correct way to update all the "people" using all CPUs?

Comment: You might try using a multi-threaded `map()` instead of multi-processing for this. See [concurrent.futures.Executor#map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map)

Comment: To be clear, this does not make sense for `multiprocessing`. The instance you fork or spawn worker processes, their objects are no longer connected to the parent process's objects. So updating a `Person` instance in place will only change the copy on the worker side, not the parent. Making your whole class multiprocessing aware using shared types from `multiprocessing` could make this work, but it's a terrible idea. The best solution is the pure functional one; pass instances in, receive new instances out to replace them, don't mutate existing instances.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I like your suggestions, and it's kind of what I was expecting. But let me rephrase. Are you saying that if I want to utilize more than one core of CPU, I should write all the functions with params and returns? Does that mean I cannot use OOP in those places at all? And there is no way I can avoid the refactoring here?

Comment: @yangliu2: Basically, yes. Like I said, classes designed to share data across processes with shared memory (or proxies) could theoretically work, but it would be both ugly and pointless (you'd spend so much time on IPC you may as well have run it in the parent process).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the response. I updated my original question at the end, please let me know what is the right way to do it at the parent process. Thanks!

Comment: As the question is currently written, it is really hard to answer it. Basically, the *direct* answer is "don't" as the scaffolding to do this via ``multiprocessing`` will cost way more than any gains. The general issue is the problem is about sharing objects, and ``multiprocessing`` is about not sharing objects. However, there are closely related *but not equal* patterns where ``multiprocessing`` could apply easily – e.g. if ``update_age`` does a lot of work, if ``people`` were already spread across processes, and so on. However, it is hard to guess which of these would match your question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the response. I don't need to use `mutliprocessing`. I just want to make this run faster, when I have millions of people object. I would have to refactor the whole thing anyway, because I cannot go further without a faster process. I'm open to go full functional programming if that's the correct way. Right now, I have a lot of work in the `update_age`. It's a bunch of updates to the person's stats. I would be interested in how to "spread people across processes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a custom function to the multiprocessing pool without the need to modify Person class. However, you don't really need multiprocessing in current case, because your `update_age` is very simple (computationally) function.

Nevertheless, if your `update_age` function would take for example 1 millisecond to complete, the use of multiprocessing will be justified.

Here is an example, where I added a small delay in update age and introduced external function to do on each person:

```
import time
import copy
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool


class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def update_age(self):
        self.age += 10
        time.sleep(0.001)


def get_updated_age(person: Person) -> int:
    person.update_age()
    return person.age


if __name__ == "__main__":
    people = [Person(random.randint(0, 60)) for _ in range(int(1e4))]
    people_copy = copy.deepcopy(people)

    start = time.perf_counter()
    results_loop = []
    for person in people:
        person.update_age()
        results_loop.append(person.age)
    print(f'Apply with loop took {time.perf_counter() - start} seconds')
    
    p = Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    start = time.perf_counter()
    results_map = p.map(get_updated_age, people_copy)
    print(f'Apply with pool map took {time.perf_counter() - start} seconds')

    print(results_loop == results_map)
```

I've created 10,000 people with random ages and applied `update_age` sequentially (in the loop) and the using multiprocessing pool. Output was as follows:

```
Apply with loop took 13.693018896 seconds
Apply with pool map took 3.141904311000001 seconds
True
```

So, you can see that multiprocessing with external function can be used to do cpu-bound operations more efficiently.

Otherwise, if the operation is not cpu-intensive (like your original +10), the sequential code will outperform multiprocessing, because of the process creation and pool manipulation costs. In case I remove `time.sleep(0.001)` the output of the above code will be

```
Apply with loop took 0.003054251000000008 seconds
Apply with pool map took 0.01680525399999999 seconds
True
```

Thus, in this case multiprocessing is not useful.

Comment: cProfile tells me that running 4000 of my `update_age` equivalent methods took about 0.3 seconds. And I want to do these updates hundreds if not thousands of times in a simulation. That's why I'm trying to spread out that function to multiple cores. I was originally concerned that I have to assign all the stats of `Person` objects after I got the updated values from multiprocessing. With millions of `Person` objects, that may not be worth doing multiprocessing. 
Now think of that, I should just go seek monte carlo simulation packages and not do this myself.

Comment: @yangliu2 what do you mean by "I have to assign all the stats of `Person` objects after I got the updated values from multiprocessing"? Each person object already contains an updated `age` value after `pool.map` function is completed. And if you don't want to return ages, it is possible to omit `return person.age`.

Comment: I misunderstood, I guess I wanted Person objects returned back. I modified it slightly and I think I got it.

Comment: @yangliu2 so, the idea works for you? Also why do you want to return Person objects back? You already have a list of Person objects which is modified internally. In my example `people_copy` would contain modified Person objects for `pool.map` way.

Comment: So in the parent process, I have a method that updates the whole simulated environment, and I need to keep track of the `Person` objects. Do you mean that when I execute `results_map = p.map(get_updated_age, people_copy)` I get all the `Person` objects in `people_copy` to update? I assume not, so I still want to update my list of `Person` using results_map as a list.

Comment: @yangliu2 yes, you get updated versions of Person objects inside `people_copy` list. So you don't have to make a new list, you can just ignore the output of the `pool.map`.